# Scrollable div with height of side div

Tags: html, css

I have two child divs side by side in a parent div. Left child div has a long list as content. It should be vertically scrollable. Right child div content will be added/removed dynamically. Its height keeps changing.

So I want left child's height to be adjusted to match the height of right child.

Is this doable with CSS

**Html**

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='left-kid'>
    Very Long content
    <hr>
    Overflow: Scroll
  </div>
  <div id='right-kid'>
    Vertically Growing Content
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left-kid {
  float: left;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#right-kid {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: How long should the left side be? You say it should be scrollable, and if that is the case it should have some initial height otherwise it will just be long as the content inside :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski That's the tricky side. No specific height here. Right kid has some content initially. So left kid should have that height. Or setting a min-height for both  kids is also fine. But still when content grows, problem exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's not possible, because the height of the right kid is dynamic, so take this height with JS and specify this height on the left kid:

```
$("#left-kid").css('height', $("#right-kid").height());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to experiment with display:table

```
#parent{
    display: table;
}  
#left-kid, #right-kid { 
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This will make both columns of equal height regardless of size increases.

Comment: But the problem is to make the left container adjust it's height to the right container, regardless if it is larger (easy) or smaller (-> here's the difficult part). I suppose that would have to be a JS solution.

Comment: Just tested it in my sandbox and it seems to work. If I add overflow:scroll to the left container and I change the right container's size, the left container follows.

Comment: Yes, but you specify height for the right container ? if i understand correctly he want dynamic height for right container and the left container follow

Answer (score 0):

> Is this doable with CSS

No. Like `Bojan Petkovski` commented, you need to somehow specify a height, otherwise the content will just expand the container.

```
#parent > div {
    height: 100%; // or some other height
}
```

The only other way to do this would be with javascript, which can determine the height each time you dynamically change the content like `AnTSaSk`'s answer.